# Android device disconnects from debugger a few seconds after breakpoint is hit

Tags: android, debugging, breakpoints

This has been plaguing me for a few days now. Any time I try to use a breakpoint to debug into anything other than an activity (background service, broadcast receiver, input method) my breakpoint will be hit normally, but then about five seconds later the device will terminate the process and disconnect from the debugger. It isn't enough time to gather any meaningful information so debugging has proven extremely difficult.

Comment: One request, one suggestion: Request: Please provide more info about what steps you are taking, what your task is doing when the breakpoint is hit, etc. It's going to be very hard to help you without that. Suggestion: You should try using the [Android Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class to print debug info. Even without a breakpoint, you'll be able to examine the logs afterwords. I've found breakpoints in Android debugging to be sufficiently tricky that I usually prefer this method. Low-tech, I know. Good luck!

Comment: Is this an "app did not respond" termination?  Did you set IsDebuggable to true in your AndroidManifest.xml?  (I'm guessing the later is "yes" because otherwise I don't think you'll ever hit a breakpoint, but I could be wrong).

Comment: What do you see in logcat when this happens?

Comment: I've discovered that this happens only when I'm testing something outside of the main app. Specifically, if I deploy the app in debug mode, then hit home and launch another application, then the breakpoint is hit. If I can make the service run while I'm still inside the app as it was launched by Eclipse then it will break just fine, even though the service that did it wasn't actually related to the activity on the screen.

Comment: This seems to be due to the builtin ANR detection kicking in. I'm seeing this too while debugging a widget. One suggestion is to set your app as the "debug app" (supposed to prevent this), but that didn't work for me while debugging a service called through a PendingIntent.

Comment: This is exactly the problem I'm having, but for me it happens only on my Oppo A53s.

Comment: I'm also running into this problem, has anyone found a solution yet? setting as "debug app" did not solve it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Well it turns out I was finally able to figure it out after setting a bounty on this question...

For me it was because of threading, it seems threads were timing out when a breakpoint has been hit in a background thread. To solve this, I changed how the breakpoint suspends the app. Instead of just suspending the thread we're currently in I changed it to suspend all instead.

Right mouse click the break point and set it to suspend all, you can also set this as default as shown below.

[image: Set suspend to all]

Answer (score 1):

I have just had the same problem

What happened for me was that I was in the middle of debugging when my phone (a ZTE blade) recieved a call. I took the call and when I came back to debugging again afterwards, I found that no matter what code I put on one particular line (probably the one where I had paused / had a break point when I recieved the call), the activity crashed (silently / without error message) when it hit that line.

After some messing around, I found if I added and removed a breakpoint on the offending line and added another in a different method later on, that the new breakpoint paused and after running the app through once, the whole thing was fine