# Debugger disconnect seconds after reach breakpoint

Tags: java, android, debugging, breakpoints, disconnect

When I am debugging an application running in my phone device, the debugger is always disconnected 30 seconds after reach a breakpoint. The error message is:

*E  ANR in com.plm.myapptest
PID: 14911
Reason: Changing to new focus window timeout
Frozen: false
Load: 22.06 / 22.39 / 22.73
----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
some avg10=0.26 avg60=0.13 avg300=0.06 total=1119102705
full avg10=0.12 avg60=0.05 avg300=0.01 total=532509077*

The issue not happen running the app in software emulator.

My phone device is Realme 7 running Android 12 and my IDE is Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Build #AI-221.6008.13.2211.9477386, built on January 11, 2023 Runtime version: 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301 amd64

The error message 'Changing to new focus window timeout' not appears in google searchs and in my opinion has not sense. A debug window should take window focus the time that the developer needs. Is there a parameter in amdroid SO to configure this timeout?

Comment: Did you visit this page? -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138001/android-device-disconnects-from-debugger-a-few-seconds-after-breakpoint-is-hit

Comment: Yes, I tried the solution proposed but did not work.